# How to prevent response on button click in code behind?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, webforms, postback, buttonclick

I have an aspx page with a form on it, the form includes an asp button that has a click handler in the code behind on the page.  I want to be able to click the button on the form, call the click handler, perform the logic in the code behind, but not return a response/postback once the click handler event finishes.

Form code:
    <%@ Page Language="vb" AutoEventWireup="false" CodeBehind="ItemEdit.aspx.vb"
    Inherits="ItemEdit" %>

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
<title>Item Edit</title>
</head>
<body>
<form id="frmItemEdit" runat="server">
<table>
    <tr>
        <td style="height: 10px; width: 100px;">
        </td>
        <td style="height: 10px; width: 100px;">
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td style="height: 21px; width: 150px; text-align: right;">
            Item:
        </td>
        <td style="height: 21px; width: 200px;">
            <asp:Label ID="lblItem" runat="server" Width="200px">
</asp:Label>
            <asp:Label ID="lblItemId" runat="server" Visible="false">
</asp:Label>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td style="height: 21px; width: 150px; text-align: right;"></td>
        <td style="height: 21px; width: 200px;">
            <asp:CheckBox ID="cbxMB" runat="server" Text="MB" 
/>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td style="height: 21px; width: 150px; text-align: right;"></td>
        <td style="height: 21px; width: 200px;">
            <asp:CheckBox ID="cbxPP" runat="server" Text="PP" />
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td style="height: 21px; width: 150px; text-align: right;"></td>
        <td style="height: 21px; width: 200px;">
            <asp:CheckBox ID="cbxB" runat="server" Text="B" />
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td style="height: 21px; width: 150px; text-align: right;"></td>
        <td style="height: 21px; width: 200px;">
            <asp:CheckBox ID="cbxT" runat="server" Text="T" />
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td style="height: 10px; width: 100px;">
        </td>
        <td style="height: 10px; width: 100px;">
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td colspan="2" style="width:350px; text-align:center;">
    <asp:Button ID="btnSave" runat="server" Text="Save" Width="100px"/>
    </td>
    </tr>
</table>
</form>
```

Code behind:
    Imports System.Data.OleDb
    Imports System.IO
    Imports System.Data.SqlClient

```
Partial Public Class ItemEdit
Inherits System.Web.UI.Page

Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) 
Handles Me.Load
    If (Not Page.IsPostBack) Then
        If Request.QueryString("itemId") IsNot Nothing Then
            Dim itemId As String = Request.QueryString("itemId")
            Dim command As New OleDbCommand("SELECT * FROM items 
WHERE id = " & itemId, New OleDbConnection(ConnectionString))
            Try
                command.Connection.Open()
                Dim reader As OleDbDataReader = command.ExecuteReader()
                If reader.Read() Then
                    lblItem.Text = reader("item")
                    cbxMB.Checked = reader("mb")
                    cbxPP.Checked = reader("pp")
                    cbxB.Checked = reader("b")
                    cbxT.Checked = reader("t")
                    lblItemId.Text = reader("id")
                End If
                reader.Close()
            Finally
                command.Connection.Close()
            End Try
        End If
    End If
End Sub

Protected Sub btnSave_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As  
System.EventArgs) Handles btnSave.Click
    Dim command As New OleDbCommand("UPDATE items SET b=" & 
Math.Abs(CInt(cbxB.Checked)) & ",t=" & Math.Abs(CInt(cbxT.Checked)) & 
",mb=" & Math.Abs(CInt(cbxMB.Checked)) & ",pp=" & 
Math.Abs(CInt(cbxPP.Checked)) & " WHERE id=" & lblItemId.Text, New 
OleDbConnection(ConnectionString))
    Try
        command.Connection.Open()
        command.ExecuteNonQuery()
    Finally
        command.Connection.Close()
    End Try
End Sub
End Class
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use Ajax. In this case, the most simple way to do that is using the Update Panel.

You have to add a ScriptManager to your page:

```
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server" />
```

And wrap the controls you want to Partial update using the UpdatePanel control:

```
 <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
            <ContentTemplate>
                    <table>
                         ... table content from example
                    </table>
            </ContentTemplate>
  </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

There are other ways to use Ajax with Asp.Net, but this is the simplest of them.

For more information about the use of Update Panel and Ajax with Asp.Net Webforms, please check:

**Introduction to the UpdatePanel Control** :
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb399001(v=vs.100).aspx

**UpdatePanel Class**:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.web.ui.updatepanel(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Could you give me an example using the code I have?  I am not familiar with ScriptManager or UpdatePanel.

Comment: Just add the Script Manager control to the page and insert all the code of the html table inside the <ContentTemplate> area of the update Panel.

Comment: Would the script manager control and the update panel both go inside of the form?

Comment: Yes, all ASP.Net server controls must be placed inside the <form runat="server"> tag.

Comment: Thank you, this was exactly what I needed.  I actually am loading this form into a jQuery UI dialog box, and am calling the button click from jQuery, then reloading parent page after form is submitted.

Comment: If it helps, please mark as answered so it can help other people.